# How to Display ANTLR Tree GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tree, antlr

How do you display the AST GUI if you have code like this, both of console or swing?
My ANTLR is version 3.

```
CharStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream("program XLSample1 =\n" + 
            "constant one : Integer := 1;\n" + 
            "constant two : Integer := 2;\n" + 
            "var a, b,c : Integer := 42;\n" + 
            "begin\n" + 
            " x:= (12 + 6) - (7 * 41) - x mod y;\n" + 
            " y := 21;\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "if x < 10 then\n" + 
            "  y :=2;\n" + 
            "  elseif x < 20 then\n" + 
            "  y := 20;\n" + 
            "  else\n" + 
            "  y := 30;\n" + 
            "end if; \n" + 
            "end XLSample1.");
    SampleLexer lexer  = new SampleLexer(stream);   
    TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    SampleParser parser = new SampleParser(tokenStream);
    parser.program();       
    System.out.println("OK");       
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Using ANTLR V4 (for V3 try to find out the similar API),to show a gui AST, you can use `org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer`.

You can get the Hello demo from [ANTLR's site](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4). Once you got it, run this simple demo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer;

/**
 * A simple demo to show AST GUI with ANTLR
 * @see http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/gui/TreeViewer.html
 * 
 * @author wangdq
 * 2014-5-24
 *
 */
public class HelloTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //prepare token stream
        CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream("hello antlr");
        HelloLexer lexer  = new HelloLexer(stream);   
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokenStream);
        ParseTree tree = parser.r(); 

        //show AST in console
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

        //show AST in GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Antlr AST");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
                parser.getRuleNames()),tree);
        viewer.setScale(1.5); // Scale a little
        panel.add(viewer);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then you will get the AST print in the console and show in `JFrame`.
more details, please refer [ANTLR API](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/overview-summary.html).

Make sure your grammar work fine, then you can modify this demo to meet your requirement.

**Update for ANTLR 4**: `TreeViewer` has moved to `org.antlr.v4.gui.TreeViewer` package from [ANTLR 4 Tool](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4).

When using `maven`, `TreeViewer` requires the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the method `r` in `ParseTree tree = parser.r();` returning ? -- I see no methods in my parser that return a `ParseTree`.

Comment: ParseTree tree = parser.translationunit();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

Answer (score 2):

After a few attempts trying to customize wangdq code, I figured out that it's possible to call the open method of TreeViewer class to get a delightful (because it's already done :)) Parse Tree Inspector.

Applied to wangdq example:

```
public class HelloTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //prepare token stream
        CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream("hello antlr");
        HelloLexer lexer  = new HelloLexer(stream);   
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokenStream);
        ParseTree tree = parser.r(); 

        //show AST in console
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

        //show AST in GUI
        TreeViewer viewr = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
                parser.getRuleNames()),tree);
        viewr.open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer in ANTLR 4...its works :)