# Using TreeViewer [Antlr4] in java only shows the full tree and not the hierarchichal data

Tags: java, swift, treeview, antlr4, jtree

I was using this found on [How to Display ANTLR Tree GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809005/how-to-display-antlr-tree-gui) but it only shows the full tree like an image and I need to have the hierarchichal tree, similar to a JTree. Is this possible?

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.gui.TreeViewer;

/**
 * A simple demo to show AST GUI with ANTLR
 * @see http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/gui/TreeViewer.html
 * 
 * @author wangdq
 * 2014-5-24
 *
 */
public class HelloTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //prepare token stream
        CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream("hello antlr");
        HelloLexer lexer  = new HelloLexer(stream);   
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokenStream);
        ParseTree tree = parser.r(); 

        //show AST in console
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

        //show AST in GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Antlr AST");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TreeViewer viewr = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(
                parser.getRuleNames()),tree);
        viewr.setScale(1.5);//scale a little
        panel.add(viewr);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[I am getting the right side, but I also want to get the left side of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cik55.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to be able to expand or collapse branches in the tree with user interaction. ANTLR's TreeViewer does not support this feature and is therefore not possible out of the box.

I do not have code ready for you, but I think your best approach is to convert ANTLR's [ParseTree](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree.html) into a Swing [JTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) by linking Swing [TreeNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html)s together. This mapping is quite straightforward and then allows you full customisability.

If you would really like to use ANTLR's representation, you would have to adapt the [TreeViewer.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TreeViewer.java) to support these user interactions.